# How to access S3 data from RStudio on EC2 using IAM role authentication?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sparklyr

I'm running RStudio on an EC2 instance that has an IAM role associated with it that allows full S3 access to it. I want to read in a file from S3 into RStudio.

I tried doing it via `sparklyr` as follows:

```
spark_install(version = "2.1.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

ctx <- sparklyr::spark_context(sc)

#Use below to set the java spark context
jsc <- invoke_static(  
  sc,
  "org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext",
  "fromSparkContext",
  ctx
)

hconf <- jsc %>% invoke("hadoopConfiguration")  
hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")  
hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
usercsv_tbl <- spark_read_csv(sc,name = "temp",path = "s3a://<bucket>/filename.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 52 more
```

I also tried using `cloudyr`'s `aws.s3` package as follows:

```
library(aws.s3)
get_bucket(bucket = <bucketname>)
```

I got the following error:

```
List of 4
 $ Code     : chr "AccessDenied"
 $ Message  : chr "Access Denied"
 $ RequestId: chr "CF4041D52D7523D2"
 $ HostId   : chr "vtkUIF7qsUwlGxBUaDpfXk9f6QHIelLxcsV0Nigla9yJicBl1YpxtrgGr82IoMyYPu6uvDSpAGI="
 - attr(*, "headers")=List of 6
  ..$ x-amz-request-id : chr "CF4041D52D7523D2"
  ..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr "vtkUIF7qsUwlGxBUaDpfXk9f6QHIelLxcsV0Nigla9yJicBl1YpxtrgGr82IoMyYPu6uvDSpAGI="
  ..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"
  ..$ transfer-encoding: chr "chunked"
  ..$ date             : chr "Mon, 28 Aug 2017 17:49:48 GMT"
  ..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
NULL
Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

How do I access S3 data using EC2's IAM role so I don't have to put in my credentials manually?

Comment: For cloudyr, you have to install the **aws.ec2metadata** package in order to pickup the EC2 metadata. You can check that it works by calling `aws.signature::locate_credentials()`

Comment: thanks! that worked!

Comment: Could you please show what worked? I have the same issue and even though I can get the credentials this way, I can't seem to get `aws.s3` to actually use them to get the bucket.

Comment: @charmander What exactly worked for you? `aws.signature::locate_credentials()` only locates credentials if you specifically defined them, but it doesn't work with a IAM role (which your question was about)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3` package when you start Spark - it allows Spark to talk to S3. The absence of this package is why you're getting the `Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found` error.

The following works for me:

```
config <- spark_config()
config$sparklyr.defaultPackages <- "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3" 
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="")
Sys.setenv(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="") # setting these blank ensures AWS uses the IAM roles associated with the cluster to define S3 permissions

sc <- spark_connect(master='xxxxx', config=config)
```

There is a good guide to this [here](https://spark.rstudio.com/example-s3.html)